# Why isn't the expression evaluating to true in this condition despite the title value being identical?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I'm writing a logic app that checks for a new feature that was created in ADO, then it would evaluate if the title has some keywords like “onboarding” and it would then create user stories, such as `story1: Onboard New Hire`, `story2: Onboard Cloud Accounts`, etc…and link them to that feature that was created

The problem is the condition statement here.

To test this, I'm creating fake feature work items with “hi” as the title of the feature, and when I trigger the run, the logic app detects the new feature that was created however the title evaluation is evaluated as “false”.

I've tried with and without double quotes, with and without wildcard *, and yet it refuses to match it!

[image: wi]

[image: lacondition]

### [image: false]

When a work item is created JSON inputs:

```
{
    "method": "get",
    "queries": {
        "account": "accountxyz",
        "areaPathComparison": "Equals",
        "iterationPathComparison": "Equals",
        "wiql__System_WorkItemType": "Feature"
    },
    "path": "/v2/workitemcreated_trigger/something%20something/_apis/wit/wiql",
    "host": {
        "connection": {
            "name": "/subscriptions/...dc/resourceGroups/rg-la/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/visualstudioteamservices-1"
        }
    }
}
```

When a work item is created JSON outputs:

```
{
    "headers": {
        "Pragma": "no-cache",
        "Transfer-Encoding": "chunked",
        "Retry-After": "15",
        "Vary": "Accept-Encoding",
        "Cache-Control": "no-store, no-cache",
        "Location": "https://logic-apis-centralus.azure-apim.net/apim/visualstudioteamservices/.../v2/workitemcreated_trigger/something%20something/_apis/wit/wiql?account=accountxyz&areaPathComparison=Equals&iterationPathComparison=Equals&wiql__System_WorkItemType=Feature&triggerState=ey...MX0=",
        "Set-Cookie": "A...1;Path=/;HttpOnly;Secure;Domain=vsts-cus.azconn-cus-001.p.azurewebsites.net,ARRAffinitySameSite=b...1;Path=/;HttpOnly;SameSite=None;Secure;Domain=vsts-cus.azconn-cus-001.p.azurewebsites.net",
        "x-ms-request-id": "0...4",
        "Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains",
        "X-Content-Type-Options": "nosniff",
        "X-Frame-Options": "DENY",
        "Timing-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "x-ms-apihub-cached-response": "false",
        "x-ms-apihub-obo": "false",
        "Date": "Tue, 01 Nov 2022 20:27:59 GMT",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Expires": "-1",
        "Content-Length": "2911"
    },
    "body": {
        "id": 31,
        "rev": 1,
        "url": "https://accountxyz.visualstudio.com/_apis/wit/workItems/31",
        "fields": {
            "System_Id": 31,
            "System_AreaId": 391,
            "System_AreaPath": "something something",
            "System_TeamProject": "something something",
            "System_NodeName": "something something",
            "System_AreaLevel1": "something something",
            "System_Rev": 1,
            "System_AuthorizedDate": "2022-11-01T20:27:59.287Z",
            "System_RevisedDate": "9999-01-01T00:00:00Z",
            "System_IterationId": 386,
            "System_IterationPath": "something something",
            "System_IterationLevel1": "something something",
            "System_WorkItemType": "Feature",
            "System_State": "New",
            "System_Reason": "New",
            "System_CreatedDate": "2022-11-01T20:27:59.287Z",
            "System_CreatedBy": "user1",
            "System_ChangedDate": "2022-11-01T20:27:59.287Z",
            "System_ChangedBy": "user1",
            "System_AuthorizedAs": "user1",
            "System_PersonId": 4...9,
            "System_Watermark": 95043,
            "System_CommentCount": 0,
            "System_Title": "hi",
            "System_BoardColumn": "New",
            "System_BoardColumnDone": false,
            "Microsoft_VSTS_Common_StateChangeDate": "2022-11-01T20:27:59.287Z",
            "Microsoft_VSTS_Common_Priority": 2,
            "Microsoft_VSTS_Common_ValueArea": "Business",
            "WEF_1...C_System_ExtensionMarker": true,
            "WEF_1...C_Kanban_Column": "New",
            "WEF_1...C_Kanban_Column_Done": false,
            "System_ExternalLinkCount": null,
            "System_IterationLevel7": null,
            "System_IterationLevel6": null,
            "System_IterationLevel5": null,
            "System_IterationLevel4": null,
            "System_IterationLevel3": null,
            "System_IterationLevel2": null,
            "System_AreaLevel7": null,
            "System_AreaLevel6": null,
            "System_AreaLevel5": null,
            "System_AreaLevel4": null,
            "System_AreaLevel3": null,
            "System_AreaLevel2": null,
            "System_Parent": null,
            "System_RemoteLinkCount": null,
            "System_HyperLinkCount": null,
            "System_AttachedFileCount": null,
            "System_AssignedTo": null,
            "System_Description": null,
            "System_History": null,
            "System_RelatedLinkCount": null,
            "System_Tags": null,
            "System_BoardLane": null,
            "Microsoft_VSTS_Common_ActivatedDate": null,
            "Microsoft_VSTS_Common_ActivatedBy": null,
            "Microsoft_VSTS_Common_ResolvedDate": null,
            "Microsoft_VSTS_Common_ResolvedBy": null,
            "Microsoft_VSTS_Common_ResolvedReason": null,
            "Microsoft_VSTS_Common_ClosedDate": null,
            "Microsoft_VSTS_Common_ClosedBy": null,
            "Microsoft_VSTS_Common_Risk": null,
            "Microsoft_VSTS_Common_StackRank": null,
            "Microsoft_VSTS_Scheduling_TargetDate": null,
            "Microsoft_VSTS_Scheduling_StartDate": null,
            "Microsoft_VSTS_Common_BusinessValue": null,
            "Microsoft_VSTS_Common_TimeCriticality": null,
            "Microsoft_VSTS_Scheduling_Effort": null,
            "Microsoft_VSTS_Build_IntegrationBuild": null,
            "Vsts_AssignedToEmail": "",
            "Vsts_WorkItemUrl": "https://accountxyz.visualstudio.com/_apis/wit/workItems/31"
        }
    }
}
```

Condition JSON definition:

```
"definition": {
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
    "actions": {
        "Condition": {
            "actions": {},
            "expression": {
                "and": [
                    {
                        "contains": [
                            "@triggerBody()?['fields']?['System_Title']",
                            "hi"
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            "runAfter": {},
            "type": "If"
        }
    },
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "outputs": {},
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
            "defaultValue": {},
            "type": "Object"
        }
    },
```

Comment: Firstly, remove the asterisks, contains doesn't need them.  That's the first thing to try.

Comment: @Skin I've tried that first thing before posting here, with and without same result. Also tried with.and without double quotes, same thing.

Comment: Can you show us a snippet of the JSON that's being evaluated?

Comment: @Skin like the raw output? It just says false

Comment: No, the data that comes out of the **When a work item is created** step.  It'll be a JSON payload, get the output of that.

Comment: @Skin see updated post with json output

Comment: Ok, that's good.  One last question though, can you provide the JSON/code definition for the condition step in question?  I want to see underlying expression it's putting together for the `contains` statement.

Comment: @Skin sure see updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the condition to the following

```
"Condition": {
    "actions": {},
    "expression": {
        "and": [
            {
                "equals": [
                    "@contains(triggerBody()?['fields']?['System_Title'], 'hi')",
                    "true"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "runAfter": {},
    "type": "If"
}
```

Comment: How can I use wildcards tho?

Comment: This should work without wildcards. If you are looking for specific location of the string then use other functions.